# Find dataframe having maximum data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a for loop in my code which generates a dataframe at every iteration which looks like this for 5 iterations

```
     year month         site  Nodata  Percentage
0    2004    08  USC00414775       0  100.000000
1    2004    09  USC00414775       0  100.000000
2    2004    10  USC00414775       0  100.000000
3    2004    12  USC00414775       0  100.000000
4    2005    01  USC00414775       3   90.322581
..    ...   ...          ...     ...         ...
110  2014    05  USC00414775       0  100.000000
111  2014    06  USC00414775       1   96.666667
112  2014    07  USC00414775       0  100.000000
113  2014    08  USC00414775       0  100.000000
114  2014    09  USC00414775       0  100.000000
115  2014    10  USC00414775       2   93.548387
```

Some dataframes have just 3 years and some have up to 20 years of data. I want to find the dataframe which has the maximum data and at the same time having max rows with percentage above 90.

Currently, I plot out every dataframe as a heatmap and then by visual inspection, pick one having the best data [image: Heatmap]

Comment: Sorry but in what variables are these stored? In different variables? Or have you concatenated them together? Would also be great if you showed us what you tried so far. Means a lot if you tried something which involves various steps (as your question does).

Comment: Currently, I don't store them. I plot out the heatmap for every dataframe and save it as a figure. Then, looking at it, I pick out the one having the best data.